# selenium error - Could not get IP address for host: 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, localhost, screen-scraping

I have a python web scraper based on selenium/phantomJS in windows.

A fare share of  http quests don't yield any response and it is unlcear why.

The logic of my code repeats those requests and the response eventually returns.

I want as many requests as possible to return data on **first attempt**.

In `logging.DEBUG`, the only thing is see is this selenium error:

```
INFO:SCRAPER_module1.py::Could not get IP address for host: 127.0.0.1
```

This was described [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2913). Quote: *"most likely the `/etc/hosts` file was changed to a domain or something else from the default 'localhost'."*

I checked my hosts file and do not see any changes of localhost.

**What is the root cause of the selenium error** `Could not get IP address for host: 127.0.0.1`**?**

**How to fix this error?**

**How to decrease the number of failed connection attempts?**